# Where does Google Desktop store a gadget that it downloaded?

Tags: path, google-workspace, google-desktop-search

I dled a gadget, "ToDo List". I want to look at its source code and such. I looked in this folder:

```
D:\Documents and Settings\Laxori\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Google Desktop\a024e0db31ec\downloaded_gadgets
```

and this one:

```
F:\Documents\My Google Gadgets
```

but the ToDo gadget wasn't there. The same with other gadgets from google, like News.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the Google's ToDo List , you can't find in those locations.Default Gadgets shifted with Google Desktop are integrated with it. You might find them in the installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/faq.html#faq_1_4

> The directory "**My Documents\My Google Gadgets**" on your machine contains all the script-based Google Desktop gadgets you've installed.
>
> These .gg files are actually zip archives. Unzip the .gg file (you may need to change the extension to .zip first if your archive utility requires it), and you'll be able to see all the source files.

Comment: That's the second directory I looked at (I renamed My Documents to just Documents). It's not there